# how to get the values of attributes from an xml doc in c# without knowing fields or anything?

Tags: c#, .net

this is my xml document

```
<Names>
    <Name1 type="M" name = "John">
    </Name1>
</Names>
```

and I want to parse through  the document so that I will get Name1,type,its value, name and its value

Comment: without knowing field? did you mean without quering for a Node(Name1) u need attibute value(type,name)? or do u mean all the inner nodes without knowing the name? i.e get all nodes inside parent node?

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlDocument class and use its ChildNodes / Attributes property.

```
var xml = "<Names><Name type=\"M\" name=\"John\"></Name></Names>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name + " : " + node.Value);
    foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(attr.Name + " : " + attr.Value);
    }
}
```

You can explore further from here, like GetElementsByTagName method or recursively explore the child nodes..

Comment: hi @AkhilSivanandan! please do post your answer as marked with 'Update' in your existing post! so that other people will also know it!

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = @"
    <parent>
      <child>
        <nested />
      </child>
      <child>
        <other>
        </other>
      </child>
    </parent>
    ";

  XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
  while (rdr.Read())
  {
    if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(rdr.LocalName);
    }
  }
```

The result of the above will be

```
parent
child
nested
child
other
```

Comment: hey abishek, am not looking for this.